# Escape single quote

Tags: support

How to escape the ` quote in inline code mode? It applies to e.g.

```
Global`
```

i.e. mathematica [context symbol](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `` Global` `` as

```
``Global` ``
```

You can choose the number of backticks to delimit inline code with.  If you choose two, then you can include one backtick in the code.  If you choose three, then you can include two, ``` StringTemplate["x = ``"][x] ```, and so on.  I wrote the previous piece of inline code as ```` ```StringTemplate["x = ``"][x]``` ````, and of course to type this in now I had to use four.